# Python dictionary, get values by key name

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have nested dictionary , trying to iterate over it and get the values by key,

I have a payload which has route as main node, inside route i have many waypoints, i would like to iterate over all way points and sets the value based on key name into a protobuff variable.

sample code below:

```
'payload':
        {
            'route':
                {
                    'name': 'Argo',
                    'navigation_type': 2,
                    'backtracking': False,
                    'continuous': False,
                    'waypoints':
                        {
                            'id': 2,
                            'coordinate':
                                {
                                    'type': 0,
                                    'x': 51.435989,
                                    'y': 25.32838,
                                    'z': 0
                                }, 
                            'velocity': 0.55555582,
                            'constrained': True,
                            'action':
                                {
                                    'type': 1,
                                    'duration': 0
                                }
                        }
                'waypoints':
                        {
                            'id': 2,
                            'coordinate':
                                {
                                    'type': 0,
                                    'x': 51.435989,
                                    'y': 25.32838,
                                    'z': 0
                                }, 
                            'velocity': 0.55555582,
                            'constrained': True,
                            'action':
                                {
                                    'type': 1,
                                    'duration': 0
                                }
                        }
                },
            'waypoint_status_list': 
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'status': 'executing'
                },
            'autonomy_status': 3
        },

#method to iterate over payload
def get_encoded_payload(self, payload):
     

      #1 fill route proto from payload
        a = payload["route"]["name"] #working fine
        b =  payload["route"]["navigation_type"] #working fine
        c =  payload["route"]["backtracking"] #working fine
        d = payload["route"]["continuous"] #working fine

     self.logger.debug(type(payload["route"]["waypoints"])) # type is dict
     
     #iterate over waypoints
        for waypoint in payload["route"]["waypoints"]:
            wp_id = waypoint["id"] # Error, string indices must be integer
```

i would like to iterate over all waypoints and set the value of each key value to a variable

Comment: Your data structure is malformed, can you post a real example?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.logger.debug(type(payload["route"]["waypoints"])) # type is dict
```

Iterating over a `dict` gives you its keys. Your later code seems to be expecting multiple waypoints as a `list` of `dict`s, which would work, but that's not what your structure actually contains.

Try `print(waypoint)` and see what you get.

Comment: thank you !    I get only keys like ``id, coordinate, velocity etc.``